# Copy-and-paste in Firefox 5.0 on OS X

Tags: support, firefox, osx

This may be an issue with my browser and operating system rather than an issue with Stack Overflow, but for some reason I can't use Command-C or Command-V for copy-and-paste operations when I compose *questions* and *answers* in Firefox 5.0 on Mac OS X (copy-and-paste operations work fine in comments, though). Interestingly enough, when I press Command-V I get the text `enter code here` instead of the content of my clipboard. (Note that CTRL-C and CTRL-V work properly in Firefox 5.0 on Windows XP.)

Has anyone else run into this? Is there an easy way to fix it?

Comment: Works fine for me in FF 5.0 on Win7 x64.

Comment: @Jon Yeah, me too (well, FF 5.0 on WinXP). The problem occurs on OS X.

Comment: Okay. Just making sure the issue is isolated. Thanks.

Comment: Does it happen only in Firefox, or Safari too?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my machine. 10.7, FF 5.0.1. Try updating Firefox, and make sure you aren't using any extensions or anything that would change shortcuts (change the browser's cmd-v and cmd-c shortcuts, or change SO's code shortcut (cmd-k by default).

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I'm using FF 5.0.1 OSX 10.6.8. I'm able to copy and paste into the answer box, or the new question input box.

Comment: @Tim I've only noticed it in Firefox.

Comment: @Nathan Now that you mention it, this may have something to do with the fact that I'm using the Dvorak keyboard layout (which maps 'k' to the Qwerty 'v'. Yup, that's exactly what it is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem appears to be caused by the Dvorak keyboard layout. Until someone figures out a better solution, I'll just switch back to a Qwerty keyboard layout whenever I want to paste something into a question or answer.

Comment: I think it would be a lot easier to just go to the Edit menu or right-click than to switch layouts each time, but up to you :-)

Comment: I use a dvorak keyboard layout (Win 7) and have no issue with copying (ie, hitting the key labeled "I" on my keyboard) or pasting (ie, hitting key labeled "." on my keyboard).  That's messed up.

Comment: @Nathan I use my MacBook's trackpad exclusively, and while I *can* right-click it's a bit cumbersome to do so. In general, I prefer keyboard shortcuts over menus, and I can simply switch keyboard layouts by pressing Command-Space.

Comment: @Rebecca Tell me about it. I think part of the problem is that Apple's default Dvorak layout actually *keeps* the Qwerty command keys, so that even while I'm typing in Dvorak I can use Command-C and Command-V just like I would on a Qwerty keyboard. That being said, I find it odd that I can paste into comments just fine—it's the question and answer fields that are giving me problems.