# Copy-Paste from the keyboard in chat in Firefox OS X

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, keyboard-shortcuts, osx

Using Firefox 7.0.1 on a Mac (OS 10.6.8) the following behaviour is reproducible:

- Select some text in chat.
- Type command-C to copy it

  - this causes a 'c' to appear in the chat input area
- Type command-V to paste it

  - this results in the following being pasted:

    ```
    (*) TeX, LaTeX and Friends | chat.stackexchange.com
    http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/<some chat room>
    ```

If I explicitly use the Edit menu instead of the keystroke, the text copies correctly.

The same issue arises in Safari 5.0.3, but not in Safari 5.1.

Note: this has nothing to do with [keyboard layout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97813/170190).

Comment: I know this is meta, but would anyone care to comment on why someone might have downvoted this? (Maybe the person who downvoted?)

Comment: I have a similar setup. When I select chat text and type **⌘C** in Safari 5.0.3, nothing is copied and my cursor moves to the input area. If I then type **⌘V**, whatever I last happened to have on my clipboard is pasted into the input area. In order to copy, I have to use the Edit menu (as you said), or right-click on the selected text.

Comment: Yes, I have known about this bug for some time. Also, the down voter probably just... doesn't like mac users? Who knows. +1 either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an keyboard event handler that checks whether the user started typing something even though they weren't in the chat input box, and (assuming that's where they wanted to type) focuses the input box in that case.

This test checks for modifier keys (since pressing Ctrl-S certainly didn't mean the user wants to start typing), but so far it was only checking for `evt.ctrlKey` and `evt.altKey`. The Mac command key sets `evt.metaKey`; this is now checked for as well.

I don't have a Mac to test it's working now, but maybe you can confirm (after possibly reloading the chat page, to ensure you have the new JavaScript).

Comment: A beyboard, it's like a keyboard for Bieber or something?

Comment: Yes; yes, that's exactly what it is.

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to have fixed it for me on Firefox.  If some of the users with Safari < 5.1 could test too and leave a comment, that would be great.  I'll leave the answer unaccepted for the moment, but the problem does seem to be fixed.

Comment: Works for me as well—yay! (and thanks)