# Consistent permalink behavior between chat and StackOverflow proper?

Tags: feature-request, chat, permalink

On StackOverflow, when I click on the "link" button beneath an answer or a question, I get this neat popup which allows me to copy the link and subsequently paste it anywhere.

[image]

In chat, when I click on the link button, I'm taken to the transcript. I would prefer the popup, so I can copy the link for use. This is especially useful for one boxed quotes and such. As it is now, I need to click the link, copy it from the new tab/window, and then paste it back into chat.

Here's the offending popup:

[image]

Comment: You can just right-click+copy instead of opening it in a new page.  You can also do that with the initial arrow on hover instead of clicking to open the popup.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how he missed that that's an `a`nchor that gets captured on click...

Comment: I've done that. Still terribly annoying to have to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *hate* those popups. So you'll have an extra hard time convincing me in particular. I accept their value in encouraging people to share the core components of our sites – questions and answers –, but I fail to see the same value for chat messages.

FWIW, especially for quoting (i.e. oneboxing), I almost never use the clipboard: I just drag & drop the little arrow next to the message to the input box (across windows, if it's from a different room). That arrow is the same link as "permalink" (so you don't even have to open that popup, as Rebecca commented), and all popular browsers except for one (I'll leave the questions which browser is being a PITA once again as an exercise to the reader) support the "drag link -> drop into text box -> URL is inserted" behavior. And it also works from the transcript, from the search results page, etc.

Comment: I can just drag and drop? Win! (I still think consistency is an issue, but this works for me too.) Now if someone were to tell my why Safari won't let me copy via keyboard shortcuts...

Comment: @Moshe did you see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108176/131541)?